# Hiding rest of the table columns starting from a column number

Tags: jquery

I'm using the below to hide one column at a time.

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

How can I used the same to hide rest of the columns from a chosen column number. For example if i have a table with 10 columns and if I mention column 5 then all columns from column 5 to 10 should be hidden.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('td:gt(4)').hide();
```

`gt` selects elements greater than passed index.

Note: Its starts from 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hiral. Can I target a specific Table with ID with this?

Comment: @Matthew welcome :). yes you can do it with specific id. say id of  your table is `mytable`, you may write: `$("#mytable td:gt(4)").hide();`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hiral. Appreciate your help.